# Symfony 3 Doctrine PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

While trying to generate a database with a command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I'm getting these errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 281
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 281
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

I have already tried all possible settings of `memory_limit` in php.ini, nothing helped.

With:

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

the errors are:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 281
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 281
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Can we see the code you are working with? It looks like your PHP app is already using 1G of RAM, which sounds very excessive.

Comment: Which part of code do you need to see? It is a complete symfony application. As far I know, the schema:update command access only the mapping files in src\AppBundle\Entity. There are 18 of them in my application. 1024M is my current setting in php.ini. When I set it to 128M the error is PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager.php on line 281

Comment: And tell us what's in your /etc/php or /etc/php5 directory.
Probably you have different settings for web server and CLI.

Comment: What happens if you use --dump-sql?  Running out of memory on a schema update is strange.  Maybe a mapping error.  And run php --ini just to double check which ini file is being used from the console.

Comment: I'm running the application locally. I've set php as environmental variable and run the application in command line. There is no such a directory like etc. Do you mean you need to see the php.ini file?

Comment: With --dump-sql I get the same error. Php --ini points on the right php.ini path. What kind of mapping problem can cause such error?

Comment: One solution is to change the `php.ini` to a large value e.g. `2048M` to see if that fixes it. However I wonder if it would be worth making the Doctrine core team aware of this in a bug report - it sounds hugely inefficient. Is `schema:update` basically a relational database migration operation?

Comment: No idea what sort of mapping error would cause this.  What does doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql do?

Comment: I've added the errors with --dump-sql to the original post. I've already tried setting the memory_limit even to 4096M, the only effect is that you have to wait longer for the error to show. When I set it to -1 (unlimited), it doesn't end and needs my whole Ram (8gb). My conclusion: there must be an infinite loop somewhere in symfony code... It doesn't really help to solve the problem.

Comment: sounds like you might've set up your entities in an infinite loop somehow

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was caused by a very specific mistake:

My User mapping had a custom repository class set up. Said repository had a constructor like the following, which caused an infinite loop:

```
public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    $this->repository = $manager->getRepository(User::class);
}
```

Since I didn't really need the custom repository, it was just a matter of removing it from the mapping.